# Is there an application I can use to protect documents?

Tags: login

Essentially I would like to have a section of a site, separate from the WP admin, that can hold documents for registered users of a certain group to view accessible only by user/password.  It would really be nice if the documents themselves could not be linked to or accessed by URL unless logged in. Please let me know of any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Hello Maxwell and welcome to WPSE :)

**I want to believe that** when you talk about:

1. an "application" on a site about WordPress, you most likely refer to a "Plugin".
2. "a section of a site, separate from the WP admin" you probably mean "A page or Post in the front-end (site/blog)"
3. "the documents themselves could not be linked to or accessed by URL unless logged in" you mean that they are "Password Protected" with a "URL that is NOT traceable".

**If my assumptions are (hopefully) correct** then you are looking for a Download Manager. There are a few in the WordPress Database and these are the links to a couple of them.

[WP-Filebase Download Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filebase/), very well supported with a sync feature. !!

[WordPress Download Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-manager/), never tried it but looks quite simple and very user friendly.

[WordPress Download Monitor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/download-monitor/) - we use it and are very happy with it. :)

Please have a look and see which one meets your needs.

---

I hope this helps. Let us know how you do,

marikamitsos

Comment: I've never used, but maybe this plugin can be modified to protect other file types: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/secure-html5-video-player/